# How do I use the '^' in this function in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

> Write a function called "computeCompoundInterest".
>
> Given a principal, an interest rate, a compounding frequency, and a
>   time (in years), "computeCompoundInterest" returns the amount of
>   compound interest generated.

```
var output = computeCompoundInterest(1500, .043, 4, 6);
console.log(output); // --> 438.8368221341061
```

Reference:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compound_interest#Calculation_of_compound_interest
This shows the formula used to calculate the total compound interest generated.

Problem is i am trying to use this formula and can't get it right

```
function computeCompoundInterest(p, i, compoundingFrequency, timeInYears) {

  p = p * (1 + (i/4)))^(compoundingFrequency*timeInYears)

}
```

I tried to step through each calculation and it looks like once I get to:

```
p = 1500 * (1 + 0.043/4)^ 4 x 6 //compoundingFrequency = 4 and timeInYears = 6
```

I am doing something wrong. This [website](http://www.thecalculatorsite.com/articles/finance/compound-interest-formula.php) seems to get a decimal number when you `(1 + (i/4)))^(compoundingFrequency*timeInYears)`

Comment: Have you tried Math.pow(x, y)?

Comment: ^ is  bitwise XOR not power.

Comment: `^` is [bitwise XOR](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Bitwise_Operators#(Bitwise_XOR)) - not `pow`.  You probably want `p = 1500 * Math.pow((1 + 0.043/4), 4) * 6`

Answer (score 4):

`^` operator is [XOR operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/pl/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Bitwise_Operators#(Bitwise_XOR)).

For exponentation you should use function [Math.pow](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/pow) (like `Math.pow(2,3) === 8`) or [`**` operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators#Exponentiation) (like `2**3 === 8`)